# Change the value of a constant in a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

My problem is that the value of β changes when the equation is =.308.
Instead of multiply β by 2, it has to be multiplied by 16.4. Thats why I thought I can add a condition in the `DSolve` part for β's value, but it isn't working.

```
η = .5; j = 0;
ν = 16.1; ω = 2 Pi ν; β = 115.95; 
ω0 = Sqrt[(ω^2) + (β^2)];
τ = (2 Pi)/ω;

ec = x''[t] + (2 β) x'[t] + (ω0^2) x[t]

sys = 
  DSolve[
    {ec == 
       Piecewise[
         {{0, ((η + j)* τ) < t < ((j + 1 ) *τ)}, 
          {.308, (j* τ) < t < ((η + j ) *τ)}}], 
         x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0},
      x, t]
Plot[x[t] /. sys, {t, 0, 1.06},
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "x[t]"}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: almost certainly you want `NDSolve` and then look at `WhenEvent` and `DiscreteVariables`

Comment: What are `j`, `η`, and `τ`?

Comment: Only constants, I'll edit the text to be more clear.

Comment: @george2079 I try using that commands but I can't, even when I change to NDSolve my code stop running.

Comment: works for me. Copied your code and fixed to `NDSolve[.., x, {t, 0, 1.06}]` and it makes a plot (fast).

Answer (score 2):

using `WhenEvent` :  ( note i changed `j` to `1` for this example )

```
η = .5; j = 1;
ν = 16.1; ω = 2 Pi ν; β = 115.95;
ω0 = Sqrt[ω^2 + β^2];
τ = 2 Pi/ω;
ec = x''[t] + 2 β x'[t] + ω0^2 x[t];
sys =
 NDSolve[{ec == f[t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, f[0] == 0,
   WhenEvent[t == j*τ, f[t] -> 0.308],
   WhenEvent[t == (η + j)*τ, f[t] -> 0]},
    {x, f}, {t, 0, 1.06}, DiscreteVariables -> {f}]
Plot[x[t] /. sys, {t, 0, 1.06}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x[t]"}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

using `Piecewise` essentially works, but there is a risk if you have a short duration impulse the automatic incrementation can skip over it.

Also for the case `j==0` here you would need to set the initial condition appropriately to `f[0]==0.308`

Comment: Thank you so much!